# Don't get value sorter when call method onChange table in react? ( I used sorter: true)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have source code below: (version antd: "^4.2.4")

column:

```
const columns = [
{
  title: 'ID',
  dataIndex: 'id',
  sorter: true,
  width: 100,
},
...
```

Table:

```
<Table rowSelection={rowSelection}
    onChange={onChangeTable}
    className='table'
    size='small'
    loading={schedules.loading}
    pagination={{
      ...PAGINATION,
      current: schedules.param.current,
      pageSize: schedules.param.pageSize,
      total: schedules.param.total,
    }}
    rowKey='id'
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={schedules.listData}
  />
```

call onChange:

```
const onChangeTable = (pagination, sorter) => {
    console.log(sorter)
}
```

console.log(sorter) is empty when I click sort at column id.

Can you help me? Thanks you very much!

Comment: Could you provide a minimum reproducible example in codesandbox or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `onChange` on the `Table` component](https://ant.design/components/table/#Table) shows the following signature:

> ```
> function(
>   pagination,
>   filters,
>   sorter, 
>   extra: { currentDataSource: [], action: paginate | sort | filter }
> )
> ```

So you need to change the callback to:

```
const onChangeTable = (pagination, filters, sorter) => {
    console.log(sorter)
}
```

[image: Edit Filter and sorter - antd@4.16.13]